# SQL Update or Insert without KEY

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

### User_ID  |  Event_ID  |  Weight

This table has no single column that is unique, however a combination of the first two columns can be unique. I would like to do an UPDATE or INSERT if doesnt exist, where the condition is if the first two columns are the same as the record I am adding. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `UNIQUE KEY` on multiple fields.  I assume that you have already done this with the two IDs.  Then, you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` since a duplicate key conflict will still be triggered.

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (:user_id, :event_id, :weight)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Weight = :weight
```

Comment: I was going to propose this, here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de6391/1